# Binlog format - RDS default

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-replication, rds

By default in MySQL 5.6 default binary logging format is "STATEMENT". 
(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-formats.html)

MySQL 5.6 running on RDS has by default format set to "MIXED" though (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html). Seems like STATEMENT is not even available.

What is the background behind this discrepancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no discrepancy.  RDS, being a managed service, does not enable every possible configurable value for every configuration parameter.

The architects of RDS chose not to make `STATEMENT` available as an option for `BINLOG_FORMAT`, presumably, because they recognize the fact that it has many limitations in a replication environment.

> Not all statements which modify data (such as `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, and `REPLACE` statements) can be replicated [correctly] using statement-based replication. Any nondeterministic behavior is difficult to replicate when using statement-based replication.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html#replication-sbr-rbr-sbr-disadvantages

Even if you don't have RDS replicas, the binary log is still used for RDS point-in-time recovery.  Without requiring at least `MIXED` logging, there would be no way for RDS to restore an instance to a point-in-time and have it guaranteed to actually be identical to the original instance at the same point in time.  Using `MIXED` or `ROW` makes that possible.

Indeed, the more confusing question is why the default value in the official distributions wasn't changed to `MIXED` back in MySQL 5.1 or 5.5.  Using `STATEMENT` mode is almost always the wrong choice.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018, AWS RDS allows the following settings for the binlog_format:
`ROW, STATEMENT, MIXED, OFF` as shown in the [official documentation of AWS RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html)

The default setting of a fresh Aurora instance is `STATEMENT`.

```
mysql>  show global variables like 'binlog_format';
+---------------+-----------+
| Variable_name | Value     |
+---------------+-----------+
| binlog_format | STATEMENT |
+---------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,08 sec)
```